# pyodbc cursor returns 0 rows from teradata

Tags: python, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

We are running - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo), with Teradata rpms:
- tdodbc1510-15.10.01.05-1.noarch
- TeraGSS_linux_x64-15.10.04.02-1.noarch
- tdicu1510-15.10.01.02-1.noarch

And connecting via pyodbc (3.0.10) with Python 3.6, like so:

> ```
> >>> import pyodbc
> >>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=devdb;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx')
> >>> curs = conn.execute('\nselect user as me')
> >>> len(curs.fetchall())
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
> ```

Also the odbc tracefile indicates successful execution but SQLRowCount = 0:

> ```
> 2759   1 TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLExecDirect returns SQL_SUCCESS   [ execute.cpp 542 ]
> 2760     TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLRowCount(hstmt5, pcrow) -->    [ results.cpp 3165 ]
> 2761   1 TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLRowCount() = 0   [ results.cpp 3212 ]
> 2762     TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLNumResultCols(hstmt5, pccol)    [ results.cpp 210 ]
> 2763   1 TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLNumResultCols ()   [ results.cpp 224 ]
> 2764   1 TS:201920:[139723593647936]   --> 0    [ results.cpp 248 ]
> 2765   1 TS:201920:[139723593647936] SQLNumResultCols returns SQL_SUCCESS   [ results.cpp 251 ]
> ```

In effect the cursor returns no results on a valid query. 
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What happens if you do `curs.nextset()` before trying to do the `.fetchall()`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue specific to using the Teradata's ODBC driver on a Linux box, for which it's been noted:
[Python with Teradata ODBC](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/python-with-teradata-odbc)
So, compiling pyodbc from source appears to have resolved the issue.
However, the ODBC driver itself is limited, in that it does not support connection pooling. Where pyodbc.pooling is True, one would have to set it as pyodbc.pooling = False, otherwise it throws the following error with pyodbc.connect:
RuntimeError: Unable to set SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING attribute.